# Motorola Radius GM300 programming help

Tags: radio-programming, motorola

What CPS (Customer Programming Software) do I use for the Motorola Radius GM300 radio.  Also, how does one add channels to it?

Answer (score 1):

Last I saw, people were using the original Motorola programming software (Motorola Radio Service Software) in a throttled DOSBox. If I remember correctly, there's also a user-written Windows software ("GM300 RadioDoctor" or so) that can do the same, but it's from the Windows 9x era, so chances are going for the original DOS software in an emulated DOS environment works more reliable.